# partner exited unexpectedly error when running perforce client

Tags: perforce, assembla

EDIT: RESOLVED! **solution:** all I did was to restart PC (not sure if this helped too), but then i logged id via console again, typed p4 client, it opened the cfg file, i closed it and then I also had to type: p4 set P4CONFIG="C:\workspace_directory\p4config.txt", now it's working.

**original issue:**
I'm trying to set up my first assembla project with perforce. "p4 info" is Ok, but I cannot run client without the error message. I already set up my connection settings into config file, if I type "p4info". Results:

```
Client name: my_name
Client host: my_host
Client unknown.
...the others seem to be fine
```

--name and host are fine, but I seem to need set up my client root workspace directory, but I was unable to find the way how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried any other commands besides 'p4 info' and 'p4 client'? 'p4 client' is trying to bring up your $P4EDITOR. Did you try a command that doesn't need to bring up an editor, like 'p4 changes', 'p4 files', 'p4 dirs'?

Comment: hello,both "p4 dirs" and "4ps files" returns: missing/wrong number of arguments. p4 changes: perforce password P4PASSWD invalid or unset even if i write manually this property to config.txt. EDIT: now i logged first and typed p4 changes: no results

Comment: That definitely makes it sound like it's a problem invoking your P4EDITOR via your connection to the Assembla server. Try a couple other editor-style commands like: 'p4 branch test-branch' and 'p4 label test-label'. Do those also give you the same error you get with 'p4 client'?

Comment: _"EDIT: RESOLVED! solution"_ - SO is not a forum.  If you have found a solution to your problem you can post it as an _answer_ below.  You can even _accept_ your own answer gaining reputation points in the process :)

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was blank P4PORT. I added P4PORT manually and the error goes away.

```
export P4PORT="p4-host:port"
```

It is surprising that the P4PORT in p4v and p4 are not in sync. I had added p4port info in p4v and it works fine but for p4 i had to add manually.